# Date in a format

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I have this code

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'-'hh:mm")
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime()
println("dateTime1 : " + dateTime1)
DateTime formattedDate = fmt.parseDateTime(dateTime1.toString());
println("formattedDate : " + formattedDate)
DateTimeFormatter finalFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'-'hh:mm");
System.out.println("formatted date : " + finalFormat.print(formattedDate));
```

It prints out something like this :

```
dateTime1 : 2014-08-20T15:34:17.256-04:00
formattedDate : 2014-08-20T16:00:17.256-04:00
formatted date : 2014-08-20T16:00-04:00
```

I want a date in exactly this format(since those are the requirements)

```
2014-08-20T15:34-04:00
```

The problem with

```
formattedDate : 2014-08-20T16:00:17.256-04:00
formatted date : 2014-08-20T16:00-04:00
```

is for time difference it always prints out '16:00-04:00'

How do I get that ? The date is retrieved from the database which will be converted in to DateTime object.

When I try this :

```
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime()
    println("dateTime1 : " + dateTime1)
    DateTime formattedDate = fmt.parseDateTime(dateTime1.toString());
    println("formattedDate : " + formattedDate)
    DateTimeFormatter finalFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'-'hh:mm");
    System.out.println("formatted date : " + finalFormat.print(formattedDate));
```

the output changes :

```
    dateTime1 : 2014-08-20T15:59:34.876-04:00
    formattedDate : 2014-08-20T15:59:34.876-04:00
    formatted date : 2014-08-20T15:59-03:59
```

It should be -04.00. But comes back as '-03:59', which is buggy.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Date isn't a String, so it has no inherent format. Instead, you have to format the date to a String. What's wrong with your "formatted date"? `16:00-04:00` is not a time difference, that's a time and utc off-set (or more commonly, a timezone).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Well, -04:00 is a UTC offset... not really a time zone as such.

Comment: @user1860447: What offset do you *want* to use? Always -04:00? Or the offset of that date/time in the system time zone? Or in a user's time zone?

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, yes that much is true. Sadly, I still don't understand OP's question.

Comment: '-04:00' is correct. But for all times to be 'T16:00', is that correct ?? I think that is what is wrong

Comment: @user1860447: How are we meant to know what is meant to be correct? That's a representation of a UTC midnight at an offset of UTC-4... we've no idea whether that's really what you want or not. It's really unclear what your inputs are, or exactly what you need your output to be.

Comment: UTC offset of -4 is correct. But is this portion 'T16:00' correct ?? The desired output format is in the question. '2014-08-20T15:34-04:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time format is incorrect, more specifically the last part makes it parse the timezone as the time of day (hours and minutes). Try using this instead:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
```

Comment: DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
        DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime()
        println("dateTime1 : " + dateTime1)
        DateTime formattedDate = fmt.parseDateTime(dateTime1.toString());
        println("formattedDate : " + formattedDate)
        DateTimeFormatter finalFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZ");
        System.out.println("formatted date : " + finalFormat.print(formattedDate)); This works !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your pattern

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'-'hh:mm"
```

When you add 'hh:mm' you are reading the time again as 04:00, however since it has read that it is a PM time already, this becomes 16:00.  You should read a timezone as a timezeone with a `Z`, not as part of the time itself.

From the Javadoc for [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
Symbol  Meaning              Presentation  Examples  
------  -------              ------------  -------
Z       time zone offset/id  zone          -0800; -08:00; America/Los_Angeles
```

and

```
Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.
```

I suggest you use

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
```

Note: the `-` at the end is not a separator, but a minus sign.  I am guessing the `-04:00` timezone is the `AEST` timezone.

Comment: How do I read timezone as a timezeone with a Z? How will the pattern change ?

Comment: @user1860447 The `Z` will read the end of the date string as the timezone.

Comment: @user1860447 What happens when you fix both format strings?

Comment: DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
        DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime()
        println("dateTime1 : " + dateTime1)
        DateTime formattedDate = fmt.parseDateTime(dateTime1.toString());
        println("formattedDate : " + formattedDate)
        DateTimeFormatter finalFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZ");
        System.out.println("formatted date : " + finalFormat.print(formattedDate));   This works

Comment: @user1860447 although it works, using `ZZ` in both formats would be more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Your offset format is incorrect `ZZ` is timezone with colon, and you need to add [`withOffsetParsed()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withOffsetParsed%28%29) -

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZ");
String dateTime1 = "2014-08-20T15:34-04:00";
DateTime formattedDate = fmt.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(dateTime1);
System.out.println("formattedDate : " + formattedDate);
System.out.println("formatted date : " + fmt.print(formattedDate));
```

Output is

```
formattedDate : 2014-08-20T15:34:00.000-04:00
formatted date : 2014-08-20T15:34-04:00
```

From the [`DateTimeFormat` javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html),

> Zone: 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon, 'ZZZ' or more outputs the zone id.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct.

But you could more simply use a [built-in formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateHourMinute()) to produce a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinute().withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC ) ; 
String output = formatter.print( DateTime.now() ) + "Z";
```

Comment: This does not give me in the format that I need, which is the UTC offset

Comment: @user1860447 I hadn't noticed that lack. I would be tempted to  just add the `Z` myself. See modified example in answer. Notice the call to `withZone` to make sure the "Z" is correct.